# What is the correct way of generating a p-value for a correlation with resampling?

Tags: correlation, p-value, resampling

I have a vector of gene expression values, across 20 patients. Each patient also has a glucose measure (a continuous numeric vector). I want to find how significant the real correlation value is compared to randomly distributed correlation values.

1. Real Pearson calculated by:

   ```
   real<-cor(gene1, glucose)
   ```
2. I generate a distribution of 10K random correlations using sample with replacement

   ```
   random_glucose <- replicate(10000,          
   cor(sample(gene1,replace=T),sample(glucose,replace=T)))
   ```

**How do I get a p-value of how significant the real is compared to the random values?**

I have tried the following:

1. Using `pnorm` with the code:

   ```
   pnorm_p <- 2*pnorm(q=abs(real),mean=mean(random_glucose),sd=sd(random_glucose),lower.tail=F)
   ```
2. I am not convinced the random values are normally distributed, so am also using `ecdf` with the code:

   ```
   ecdf_calc<-function(real, random_glucose){
     funny<-ecdf(random_glucose)
     value<-funny(real)
     if(value<=0.5){
       res<-2*value
       return(res)
     }else{
       res<-((1 - value)*2)
       return(res)  
     }
   }
   ```

What are the right ways to do it with `ecdf` and `pnorm`?

I see different ways of doing this via Google and I don't understand the difference.

E.g., methods using Z-scores as here; 
http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/pValues.html#calculating-a-single-p-value-from-a-normal-distribution

And sometimes I see `1-pnorm(...)` and others I see `pnorm(..)` alone without the `1-`.

Comment: For a one tailed test, you just count how far in it is from the end. For two tailed it's a little more complicated, but still quite simple.

Comment: You didn't ask about it but your resampling approach is somewhat odd. If this is a bootstrap, you ought to resample **actual pairs** of gene-glucose values. If this is a permutation test, you ought to resample values **without replacement** - effectively shuffling one of the value vectors (either genes or glucose values). In your case I'd prefer a permutation approach over bootstrap (given enough replications the permutation-test p-value is exact, with bootstrapping it's hard to be sure).